# MultinomialLogit() with xlogit - ValueError: inconsistent 'y' values. Make sure the data has one choice per sample

Tags: python, sample, multinomial, mlogit

I'm learning about multinomial logit and I have a problem running this code using xlogit.

```
# Long format
from xlogit.utils import wide_to_long
ATUS_data_LA_2020_Long = wide_to_long(ATUS_data_LA_2020_wide, id_col='custom_id', alt_name='alt', sep='_',
                  alt_list=['Non-Shopping', 'In-store Shopping', 'Online Shopping', 'Both'], empty_val=0, alt_is_prefix=True)
# List of variables 
index_var_names = ['MSASIZE','FAMINCOME','AGE_1','SEX','EDUC','EMPSTAT','DIFFMOB_1','FSTRUC']

# Reshape
y = ATUS_data_LA_2020_Long['DEPVAR_1'].values.ravel() # reshape 1 dimension
alt = ATUS_data_LA_2020_Long['alt'].values.ravel() # reshape 1 dimension

# Model
from xlogit import MultinomialLogit
model = MultinomialLogit()
model.fit(X=ATUS_data_LA_2020_Long[index_var_names],
          y=y,
          varnames=index_var_names,
          ids=ATUS_data_LA_2020_Long['custom_id'],
          alts=alt,
          fit_intercept=True,
          weights=np.asarray(ATUS_data_LA_2020_Long['WEIGHT']))
model.summary()
```

I got this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[14], line 40
     38 from xlogit import MultinomialLogit
     39 model = MultinomialLogit()
---> 40 model.fit(X=ATUS_data_LA_2020_Long[index_var_names],
     41           y=y,
     42           varnames=index_var_names,
     43           ids=ATUS_data_LA_2020_Long['custom_id'],
     44           alts=ATUS_data_LA_2020_Long['alt'],
     45           fit_intercept=True,
     46           weights=np.asarray(ATUS_data_LA_2020_Long['WEIGHT']))
     47 model.summary()

File ~\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\xlogit\multinomial_logit.py:139, in MultinomialLogit.fit(self, X, y, varnames, alts, ids, isvars, weights, avail, base_alt, fit_intercept, init_coeff, maxiter, random_state, tol_opts, verbose, robust, num_hess, scale_factor)
    134 self._validate_inputs(X, y, alts, varnames, isvars, ids, weights)
    136 self._pre_fit(alts, varnames, isvars, base_alt, fit_intercept, maxiter)
    138 betas, X, y, weights, avail, Xnames, scale = \
--> 139     self._setup_input_data(X, y, varnames, alts, ids, 
    140                            isvars=isvars, weights=weights, avail=avail,
    141                            init_coeff=init_coeff,
    142                            random_state=random_state, verbose=verbose,
    143                            predict_mode=False, scale_factor=scale_factor)
    145 tol = {'ftol': 1e-10}
    146 if tol_opts is not None:

File ~\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\xlogit\multinomial_logit.py:276, in MultinomialLogit._setup_input_data(self, X, y, varnames, alts, ids, isvars, weights, avail, base_alt, fit_intercept, init_coeff, random_state, verbose, predict_mode, scale_factor)
    271 def _setup_input_data(self, X, y, varnames, alts, ids, isvars=None,
    272         weights=None, avail=None, base_alt=None, fit_intercept=False,
    273         init_coeff=None, random_state=None, verbose=1, predict_mode=False,
    274         scale_factor=None):
    275     self._check_long_format_consistency(ids, alts)
--> 276     y = self._format_choice_var(y, alts) if not predict_mode else None
    277     X, Xnames = self._setup_design_matrix(X)
    278     N, J, K = X.shape

File ~\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\xlogit\_choice_model.py:193, in ChoiceModel._format_choice_var(self, y, alts)
    191     return y1h
    192 else:
--> 193     raise ValueError("inconsistent 'y' values. Make sure the "
    194                      "data has one choice per sample")

ValueError: inconsistent 'y' values. Make sure the data has one choice per sample
```

The data has same number of rows for all columns. Also, 'y' doesn't have missing values.

```
print(y.shape)
print(alt.shape)
----------------
(1420,)
(1420,)
```

When I use reshape this is what happen

```
y = np.array(ATUS_data_LA_2020_Long['DEPVAR_1']).reshape(len(ATUS_data_LA_2020_Long['alt']), 1).astype(int)
---------------
ValueError: y must be an array of one dimension in long format
```

My 'y' = 'DEPVAR_1' have four possible values {1,2,3,4}, which means 1:'Non-Shopping', 2:'In-store Shopping', 3:'Online Shopping', 4:'Both'

[image]

I looked for similar questions but none of them solve my problem.
I'm using Python 3.10.11.

I want suggestions to solve the error of inconsistent 'y' values

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does your `y` data look like?  Are some of the values empty strings?

Comment: Hi, @TimRoberts 'y' have four possible values {1,2,3,4}, which means 1:'Non-Shopping', 2:'In-store Shopping', 3:'Online Shopping', 4:'Both'

Comment: But `MultinomialLogit` wants to see the actual string values, right?  Your `alt` values have the strings, don't they?

Comment: The wide format of my data has cumulative values in independent columns of 'Non-Shopping', 'In-store Shopping', 'Online Shopping', 'Both'. I applied long format calling those columns with the alt_list in the wide_to_long function. So I suppose this is the string.